# javascript input field doesn't trigger boolean in smart contract correctly

Tags: solidity, javascript

In one of my smart contracts I have the following function:

```
function dosomething(bool _okl) {
    if (_okl == false){
        boola = true;
        boolb = false;
        nextstep();
    } else {
        boolb = true;
        nextstep();   
    }
}
```

I have a frontpage where bool _ok can be filled in by an input field:

```
input type="text" name="_okl" id="_okl" placeholder="true or false"
```

and button:

```
button id="button3">OK? button
```

this button is triggering my dApp.js in the following way:

```
$("#button3").click(function() {
    contractED.dosomething({value: $("#_okl").val()}, function(err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);
    })
});
```

For some reason, if I enter false in _okl, my contract doesn't recognize it as such in the logical check. What am I doing wrong here? It is triggering the function just fine, but always goes directly to the else part of my function.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe $("#_okl").val() return a String, and therefore _okl is always true

Comment: Solved it in the end by creating seperate functions with corresponding seperate buttons to update booleans to either true or false.